# How to parse json with different key names and similar objects in each key?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have this JSON :

```
  {
  "response": {
     "PEOPLE": {
      "PERSON1": {
        "name": "jon",
        "last": "jony"
      },
      "PERSON2": {
        "name": "mike",
        "last": "mikey"
      }
    }
  }   
 }
```

How can I parse it to a dictionary which the key will be the `PERSONX` string?

I'm new to c#, and know that in Java I need to have one class, where internal key will be : `"person_name`"...

Comment: Have you looked into Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: no, I looked at the  System.Runtime.Serialization.. I thought this is the one I need

Comment: Why is it tagged 'json.net' then?

Comment: For Json. Newtonsoft.Json will be your friend

Comment: Read any/all of the questions to the Right under **Related**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest create a class because it's easier to work and you have full control of it.

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string,Person> People{ get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

When properties have different names I use Dictionary and then you can use LINQ to access them.

Get value of a dictionary:

var valueOfFirstPeopleElement = People.FirstOrDefault().Value;

This way you have the person class.

In order to parse the json to this class you must deserialize using a json converter.

```
Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonData);
```

To do the reverse you Serialize instead.

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.